# How to find image in div with help PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, css

Have div and in div image:

```
<div class="post entry-content ">

<img class="bbc_img" alt="Posted Image" src="http://example.com/image.jpg">

</div>
```

I need fing image in div with help php, it is same as with this code:

```
preg_match('IMAGE.JPG', $DIV_CLASS, $matches); 
if ($matches[1])
{
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Or find image with class="bbc_img" in html

Comment: Want to use `jQuery`...?

Comment: `regex` are notoriously tricky and unreliable for this sort of task - you would be better, imo, using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` - or even the equivalent javascript methods

Comment: but why? What are you trying to do? PHP/Jquery/CSS tags? which one?

Answer (score 2):

To do this with `DOMDocument` and `XPath` is much simpler than using a regex

```
$strhtml='
    <div class="post entry-content">
        <img class="bbc_img" alt="Posted Image" src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
    </div>';

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $col=$xp->query('//div[ contains(@class,"entry-content" ) ]/img[@class="bbc_img"]');

    if( $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->getAttribute('src');
    }
```

Comment: This working for me. Thank you. But http://example.com/image.jpg this image can be a random from random url.

Comment: The same code can be used but you'd need to edit the XPath query to suit the html content - or simply make a very greedy pattern such as `$xp->query('//img');` ~ if you posted the actual use-case code it would help clarify further

Comment: I`m sorry. I`m not a coder with php. Please write full code.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery, you can easily do this with the help of DOM parsing.

HTML

```
<div class="post-entry-content">
  <img class="bbc_img" alt="Posted Image" src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".post-entry-content .bbc_img").length > 0) {
    alert("div contains image with class bbc_img");
  }
});
```

Refer this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lwv7q09c/

Comment: the question does explicitly say `with help PHP`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$div= '<div class="post entry-content ">
<img class="bbc_img" alt="Posted Image" src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
</div>';

preg_match('/src="(.*)"/i', $div, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$img = $matches[0][0];
```